# LaTeX foreach with non-numerical indices

Tags: foreach, tikz-pgf

I'm writing a simple script to produce randomized cards that I use to teach statistical ideas in my class. I've used Tikz to produce randomized cards that all follow the layout that I want using nested foreach loops. However, I'm seeing an odd artifact that I can't track down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,pgfmath}


\begin{document}

%Define a vector of dog breeds: breed,breed image,lower random effect level, upper random effect level, and effect level offset
\newcommand{\dogBreeds}{Akita/Akita.png/0/5/5,Beagle/Beagle.png/6/12/0,Collie/Collie.png/28/40/0,Dalmatian/Dalmatian.png/30/45/75}%\newcommand{\dogBreeds}

%Define vectors of values for the (x,y) center of each card
\newcommand{\xCardColumnCenters}{2.5,6}
\newcommand{\yCardRowCenters}{1.5,3.5,5.5,7.5,9.5}

%Define vectors of x values for the Edge of each card
\newcommand{\xCardLeftEdge}{0.75,4.25}
\newcommand{\xCardRightEdge}{4.25,8}

%Define vectors of y values for the Edge of each card
\newcommand{\yCardLowerEdge}{0.5,2.5,4.5,6.5,8.5}
\newcommand{\yCardUpperEdge}{2.5,4.5,6.5,8.5,10.5}

%iterate through the dog breeds
\foreach \breed / \image / \lower / \upper / \offset in \dogBreeds{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    %remember picture, overlay allow us to use absolute measurements on the page, ignoring any margins
        %iterate through the y and x columns to build a matrix of cards
        \foreach \y in \yCardRowCenters {
            \foreach \x in \xCardColumnCenters  {
                %center and scale the image using (x,y) relative to the page in absolute coordinates
                \node[xshift=\x in,yshift=\y in,anchor=center](image) at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[height=1.5 in]{\image}};
           }%\foreach \x in \xCardColumnCenters
        }%\foreach \y in \yCardRowCenters

        \foreach \x in \xCardRightEdge  {

           \foreach \y in \yCardRowCenters {
               \node[fill=white,xshift=\x in,yshift=\y in,rotate=90,anchor=south] at (current page.south west) {\huge{\textbf{BREED}}};
           }%\foreach \y in \yCardRowCenters

        }%\foreach \x in \xCardRightEdge  {

        \foreach \x in \xCardLeftEdge  {

           \foreach \y in \yCardUpperEdge {
               \node[fill=white,xshift=\x in,yshift=\y in,anchor=north west] at (current page.south west) {\Large{\breed}};
           }%\foreach \y in \yCardRowCenters        

            \foreach \y in \yCardLowerEdge {
                %create a random effect size
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\effect}{random(\lower,\upper)-\offset};
               \node[fill=white,xshift=\x in,yshift=\y in,anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\Large{Effect: $\effect$}};
           }%\foreach \y in \yCardLowerEdge

        }%\foreach \y in \yCardRowCenters
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \clearpage
}%\foreach \breed in \dogBreeds

\end{document}
```

This produces the desired output, with one exception. At the top of every new page, it places a single number (the first number in the \dogBreeds command) at the top of each page. I'm not sure what's causing this; I tried creating a numerical index at the start of each set of entries, but that didn't remove this effect. Very strange. Ideas?

Comment: Since you are using pictures in your code, it is preferable to provide a snapshot for the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: ![Problem Example](http://i.imgur.com/Pm96pAW.png)

Note the number printed at along the top margin; this occurs in all pages, each time printing the first number (referred to in the comment as 'lower random effect level').

Comment: A little more prodding seems to isolate the problem to the code:

`\foreach \breed/\image/\lower/\upper/\offset in \dogBreeds{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,scale=1]'
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
}`

The macro definition seems to hold up without creating a new tikz environment in foreach. The code within the tikz environment seems to hold up without the foreach. But when I declare a new tikz environment using foreach, it places that numeral on the top page edge and throws the error "Missing number, treated as zero".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your variable name other than `\lower`. In fact always use `\my<macro>` name to make sure that you are not clashing with a TeX primitive.